# Determine the image of the strip $S$ consisting of all points $z$ with $\frac{-\pi}{2}\lt Re(z) \lt \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $Im(z)>0$ under $w=i\sin z$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, transformation, conformal-geometry

$\color{green}{\text{transformation is}\space w=i\sin z}$

$$w=i\sin z = i\sin(x+iy)=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{ix-y}-e^{-(ix-y)}\right)=-\cos(x)\sinh(y)+i\sin(x)\cosh(y)$$

$\therefore u = -\cos(x)\sinh(y) \tag{1}$

$\color{green}{\text{and }} v = \sin(x)\cosh(y) \tag{2}$

$\color{green}{\text{1.Transformation for }\space y>0 \space \text{i.e.} \space \operatorname{Im}(z)>0}$

using $(1)$ and $(2)$ :

$\dfrac{v^2}{\sin^2(x)}-\dfrac{u^2}{\cos^2(x)} = \cosh^2(y)-\sinh^2(y) \tag{a}=1$

$\color{red}{\text{don't know if it is legal to do this but i now assume} \sin(x) \text{ and } \cos(x) \text{ are constant terms}}$

$\therefore \dfrac{v^2}{\alpha^2}-\dfrac{u^2}{\beta^2} = 1$ therefore line $y>1$ transforms into a hyperbola

$\color{green}{\text{2.Transformation for }- \pi /2 \lt \operatorname{Re}(z) < \pi/2 \space }$

using $(1)$ and $(2)$ same way as in $(a)$

$\dfrac{v^2}{\sinh^2(x)}+\dfrac{u^2}{\cosh^2(x)} = \cos^2(y)+\sin^2(y) \tag{b}=1$

$\therefore \dfrac{v^2}{A^2}+\dfrac{u^2}{B^2} = 1$

is this the correct way to do this transformation?, thank you for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*small correction

" ... therefore line $y>\color{red}{0}$ transforms ..."

It's looking good, the last part would be an ellips. When $x$ is big enough it would start looking like a circle (since $\cosh x \approx \sinh x$ when $x$ big enough)

Also, sure it is legal to perform that first transformation. You just take $x$ constant to investigate the effect of a change in $y$. (a vertical line)

**But** then you would need to know what bounds come into play. As Michael also stated:

$$\begin{align}
u &= -\cos x \sinh y\\
v & = \sin x \cosh y
\end{align}$$

Note that $\sinh y \in {]0, +\infty[}$ and $\cosh y \in {]1, +\infty[}$ if $y>0$.

And $-\cos x \in {[-1,0[}$ and $\sin x \in {]-1,1[}$ if $x\in {\left]-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right[}$

Looking for upper bounds, $u$ will always consist of a negative number multiplied with values which go from 0 to $\infty$. In conclusion: $u \in {]-\infty, 0[}$ while $v$ can be either positive and negative while taking all values. $v\in \mathbb{R}$.

#### End result

$w \in \{ z \in \mathbb{C}: \operatorname{Re}z < 0\} $

#### Note

I like your calculations too, they show a **deeper understanding** of the map. (nice!)

I'va added a drawing where you can see the map taking an effect on a horizontal like and a vertical line. You can download the GeoGebra document here: http://tinyurl.com/ndjsn4o so you could play around with the points itself.

[image: map]

(this might be a bit overkill as an answer though ;) )

Comment: :) Thanks for answering the question in the way i attempted it, thanks for the ggb sketch as well. One last thing(s) how would i actually go about drawing this on paper say if it were an exam, say for $(a)$ can i just plug in fixed points for x between the bounds on $Re(z)$ and then plot point by point? such that i maybe get something like [this][1], and also why are your graphs in left hand plane and not like the one on wolfram plot?. 


  [1]: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y%5E2-x%5E2%3D1

Comment: (a) The best way if finding the region on paper is to consider where $u$ and $v$ 'live' if $x$ and $y$ are limited to a certain domain. You don't really need a drawing for that. (b) The graphs are only in the left plane because of the calculations from (a). For example if $y$ would not have been restricted then $\sinh y$ could also be negative $\Rightarrow u \in \mathbb{R}$. In conclusion: the map turns horizontal lines into ellipses and vertical lines in hyperbolas. Putting a restriction on the map limits where these figures can be drawn.

Comment: I don't really get the sketch, what do you want to draw?

Comment: :) i was attempting to draw $-\pi /2<Re(z)<\pi /2$ and $Im(y) >0$

Comment: You mean $\operatorname{Im}z > 0$ ;). You've got the axis wrong. If $z = x+iy$ then $\operatorname{Re} z = x \in {\left]-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right[}$ and $\operatorname{Im}z = y > 0$. In my picture denoted as the region between the dashed lines and above de $x$-axis.

Comment: i think i understand $y>0$ but $x> -\pi /2$ and $x< \pi/2$ is that not like saying where $x = i$ ?? anyway so you saying switching the axis label on my "sketch" makes it right?.. thanks for your patience.

Comment: No. If $z=x+iy$ then $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $y\in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow x$ cannot be $i$. But $z=i = 0+1\cdot i$ does indeed meet the conditions.

Answer (score 2):

So firstly note that you've let $x$ and $y$ represent $\mathrm{Re}(z)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(z)$ respectively. Therefore since $\frac{-\pi}{2} < \mathrm{Re}(z) < \frac{\pi}{2}$, neither $\mathrm{sin}(x)$ nor $\mathrm{cos}(x)$ are constant over the region.

There is a simpler way to solve this. Go back to $w = u +  \mathrm{i}v$, with $u = -\cos(x)\sinh(y)$ and $v = \sin(x)\cosh(y)$. This bit is correct.

Since $\frac{-\pi}{2} < \mathrm{Re}(z) = x < \frac{\pi}{2}$, so $ 0 < \cos(x) < 1$ and $-1 < \sin(x) < 1$. Also $\mathrm{Im}(z) = y > 0$, so $\cosh(y) > 1$ and $\sinh(y) > 0$.

Then we can look at how this bounds $u$ and $v$. We get $u = -\cos(x)\sinh(y) < 0$  as any negative quantity (as it is the negative of the product of two positive quantities, one unbounded) and $v = \sin(x)\cosh(y) \in \mathbb{R}$ as any real number (as it is a positive, negative, or zero multiple of any positive real number).

So $\mathrm{Re}(w) < 0$ and $\mathrm{Im}(w) \in \mathbb{R}$.